# Obtaining a plot which shows the three quantities in a single point?

Tags: matplotlib, matlab-figure

Let's say I have a timeseries dataset for a particular quantity `Quantity`.

In addition to that I also have two constant values `Q_low` and `Q_high` which represents the minimum and maximum values that `Quantity` can get.

What I need to get is an error bar sort of plot which I can use to show the variation of `Quantity` within the lower and upper limit for the entire duration.

Can anyone please help me how to obtain this sort of a plot in either matplotlib or MATLAB ?

I tried using the box-plot but it will consider the min and max values depending on the dataset but not the user specified values.

Thanks.

Comment: All text but no data or code in a coding question is a very bad practice. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`plt.axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axhspan_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axhspan-demo-py) could be helpful. E.g. something like `plt.axhspan(Q_low, Q_high, facecolor='crimson', alpha=0.4)`

Comment: @JohanC This seems useful. Thanks.